# Shiny server running on localhost can't be accessed from web when redirected by apache

Tags: r, shiny, apache2, shiny-server

Hello dear stackoverflow!

I'm having trouble setting up shiny server and apache2 routing.
Roughly following this guide https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213733868-Running-Shiny-Server-with-a-Proxy (but with apache2)

I set up shiny to run on my **127.0.0.1:2224** port. Everything works just fine when I open a tunnel and port forward, I see my app on localhost.

I set up pwd and redirection in apache as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin karin@localhost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPass "/myapp" "http://localhost:2224"
    ProxyPassReverse "/myapp" "http://localhost:2224"

   <Location /myapp>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Enter your login name and password"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
   </Location>
```

And when I open public **my.ip/myapp** I am prompted to log in, and after doing so I am redirected to local port 2224, yay!

~ however, the app seems to be broken. I can't see any of the resources, images, css - just the plain interface as coded in the app ui.R

I see a plenty of [404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sCpu.png) in logs, the shiny server is looking for all these resources on the web, with address **my.ip/shared/whatever** - but the resources are accessible only through **localhost:2224/shared/whatever**

...

any idea where I messed up the routing? What privileges are missing, or what to try to be able to access my app without setting up ssh tunnel and port forward?

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Roughly following this guide https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213733868-Running-Shiny-Server-with-a-Proxy (but with apache2)

I have had success in using apache2 as a reverse proxy for shiny server when following that guide in detail, in particular the last examples. In your case, you should replace

```
ProxyPass "/myapp" "http://localhost:2224"
ProxyPassReverse "/myapp" "http://localhost:2224"
```

with

```
 RedirectMatch permanent ^/myapp$ /myapp/

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
 RewriteRule /myapp/(.*) ws://localhost:2224/$1 [P,L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
 RewriteRule /myapp/(.*) http://localhost:2224/$1 [P,L]
 ProxyPass /myapp/ http://localhost:2224/
 ProxyPassReverse /myapp/ http://localhost:2224/

 Header edit Location ^/ /myapp/
 ProxyRequests Off
```

Comment: Aaaaah, I was using a simple app without resources to test, everything worked and now I was wondering why it all of a sudden does not. *facepalm* You're right, reading manuals, thanks a lot!